# An issue with different platform toolset

Tags: c++, .net, api, managed-c++

There is a DLL written in C++ and built with th **v90 Platform Toolset**.
This DLL should be used as an API in the managed C++ project based on .NETFramework 4.0 where the Platform Toolset is **v100**.
I can't call any methods from the API unless I downgrade the platform of managed c++ project from **v100** to **v90**.

Please advise whether there is a way to avoid changing the platform and how to perform calls from **v100** platform to **v90**?

Comment: Have you tried statically linking the DLL with v90?